# Почему mime_types не правильно определяется?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста почему мое загруженное изображение JPEG определено неправильным типом

правильный параметр должен быть image/jpeg на сколько я понимаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
      $mime_types = ['image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'];

      Validator::extend('is_image_array', function($attribute, $values, $params, $validator) use ($mime_types) {

          foreach ($values as $k => $value) {
              $f = finfo_open();

              $result = finfo_buffer($f, base64_decode($value), FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

              dd($f, $value,$result, $mime_types);
              if ( !in_array($result, $mime_types)){
                  return false;
              }
          }
          return true;
      });
```

Comment: не только image/jpeg. может еще и image/x-citrix-jpeg и image/jpeg и даже (вроде бы) image/pjpeg. Посмотрите на mime-type, который к Вам приходит

Comment: Зачем Вы изобретаете велосипед? Обычный валидатор из коробки может вполне себе чётко определять, какой mime пришёл...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar подобная реализация на просторах интернета для валидации изображений в base64. Можете ли пожалуйста привести пример валидатора из коробки как это должно выглядеть? я познаю laravel может что то не углядел

Comment: Видимо ваша локальная база "магических" данных, которая идёт вторым параметром функции finfo_open, не предоставляет данных о файле, который вы пытаетесь определить. Вы можете попробовать обновить эти базы как указано в комментариях [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.finfo-open.php)

Comment: @Vlad Да, наврал, сорри. Но есть [такой пакет](https://github.com/crazybooot/base64-validation), который проверяет спокойно base64